# Angular IBM Bluemix Cloudant Example Code

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud, cloudant

Does anyone have any example code for using an Angular 2 web app to CRUD data from a Cloudant database on IBM Bluemix? I have had some success developing an Ionic 2 application to do so. However, I am not sure how I can do the same for a standard Angular 2 Web App. I have been unable to find any good tutorials online.

Answer (score 5):

Cloudant does not have the library support for Angular 2, so please call HTTP requests to Cloudant database through your Angular 2 web app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Cloudant library for Angular yet.

To develop a Cloudant communication in Angular, there are at least 2 options :

- **Code an HTTP service in Angular with the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)**. Exemple : [How to code a Cloudant service with Angular](https://medium.com/@adrienarcuri/how-to-code-a-cloudant-service-with-angular-b2c371fb4fdb?source=---------2------------------) (Link to Medium)
- **Use [Cloudant NodeJS Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cloudant/cloudant) and adapt it to TypeScript**. Exemple : [See this article on Cloudant Blog](https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/06/29/Modelling-Cloudant-Data-in-TypeScript.html) (link to Cloudant Blog)